# What is a general entangled bipartite system?

Tags: entanglement

Is there a general pure entangled bipartite system that all other entangled bipartite systems are a special case of it?

Comment: It's much easier the other way: there is a general separable bipartite state $\sum_i p_i \hat{\rho}_i\otimes\hat{\sigma}_i$ such that all other separable bipartite states are a special case of it. Then entangled states are all of the states not belonging to this.

Comment: I want a same formula for entanglement, if it is exist.

Comment: What does a state being a "special case" of another state mean?

Comment: It means u can make any pure entangled bipartite state via it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see the question asked about pure states - then yes! A general entangled pure state takes the following form, via the Schmidt decomposition:
$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_i \psi_i |a_i\rangle\otimes |b_i\rangle$$ for some non-negative coefficients $\psi_i$ and some pure states $|a_i\rangle$ and $|b_i\rangle$. To be entangled, more than one of the coefficients $\psi_i$ must be nonzero. This is a bit of a strange way of writing the set, but we can be clever and say that any state of the form of $|\Psi\rangle$ with all Schmidt coefficients $|\psi_i|<1$ is entangled. Unentangled states are those with the same form but with one of the coefficients having magnitude equal to unity.